# How to forward port from internal interface to virtual machine in local network?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vmware-server, port-forwarding

I want to forward a port from internal, internet interface of my server running `Windows Server 2008 Enterprise SP2 x64` to virtual machine running on VMware Server 2.0.2 that is in a local network (10.0.0.0).

How can I do that without using ISA Server?

Comment: I take it you're not running ISA on the 2008 server?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to use [Routing and Remote Access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754634(WS.10).aspx) built into Windows 2008. You can setup [port forwarding](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779893(WS.10).aspx) within it from a specific interface to whatever destination you need.

If that option isn't available you might try something like this simple [PortForward](http://www.quantumg.net/portforward.php) program. It would be nice if it let you choose the NIC it was looking at, but who can argue with the price.